# Can't change user permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I just mounted my Apple Time Capsule to my pi, but for some reason I cannot change, add, or remove any content from the directory.

I have tried changing permissions from my username and from root but am having no luck, nothing changes.

The directory is `/home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule`
and the Owner and Group are both set to `ddrossi93` (I have a group named this as well). Permissions are anyone can view and access, but only the owner can change content. I am 99% sure I am logged in as `ddrossi93`, the owner.

The folder within the directory `/home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule/Downloads` has a different owner and group.

the owner and group are both root.
Anyone can view and access, but only the owner can change content.

I have tried the following lines in terminal, but nothing has changed.

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule/Downloads
sudo chown -R ddrossi93 /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule
sudo chown -R ddrossi93 /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule/Downloads
```

I ran all these commands from both `ddrossi93@raspberrypi` and `root@raspberrypi`, neither have changed a thing.

Comment: How does the mount command looks like? Just to be sure for ownership is correctly to ddrossi93 run `sudo chown ddrossi93:ddrossi93  /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule`. If done try to create, edit and delete a file in /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule/Downloads localy on the Pi. When i remember correctly, there are different methods to run the Pi as a Time Capsule. Can you provide some more information what you installed and configured?

Comment: @JoePlatano sudo mount.cifs "//192.168.1.105/Time Capsule/" /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsure -o username=username,password=password,sec=ntlm

Comment: @JoePlatano tried adding a folder to /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule/Downloads and permission wad denied

Comment: @JoePlatano I have not installed or configured anything else related to this

Comment: can you create files or folders when you logged in to your raspberry (by ssh or directly with keyboard and monitor? for mounting your time capsule try this : `sudo echo "//192.168.1.105/TimeCapsule/ /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule cifs user=ddrossi93,pass=ddrossi93Password,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0" >> /etc/fstab` then run `sudo mount -a`

Comment: @JoePlatano it did not mount anything.

Comment: does this line showvup in /etc/fstab? you can also try sudo mount.cifs with the parameters that i gave you. just ensure to unmount the old mounts before

Comment: @JoePlatano yes, it is there

Comment: @JoePlatano but it does not automount after reboot

Comment: check what is mounted (mount), if /home/ddrossi93 is mounted unmount with umount /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule and then mount -a to mount the fstab listening

Comment: maybe the network is not up when fstab will be executed. run mount -a manually. if this mounts the TimeCapsule, you can try to mount when the network comes up `sudo echo "//192.168.1.105/TimeCapsule/ /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule cifs user=ddrossi93,pass=ddrossi93Password,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0" >> /etc/network/if-up.d/fstab` make the file executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/fstab` and check what happen on reboot

Comment: everything in if-up.d will be executed when the network is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much research I found my answer.

I unmounted what I had and started from scratch.

I then remounted using this line in the terminal logged in as the user ddrossi93:

```
sudo mount.cifs "//192.168.1.105/Time Capsule/Downloads" /home/ddrossi93/TimeCapsule -o username={username},password={password},sec=ntlm,forceuid,forcegid,uid=ddrossi93,gid=ddrossi93,rw
```

I hope this helps someone in the future so they don't have to go through hours of trying to figure it out.

Thanks to Joe Platano for giving suggestions.